# How can we create custom attribute in .net core to check the session activated

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to create custom attribute which will help me to check session. But in .net core I am not able to handle session outside the controller. After researching I get this code on the net,
But when i try to write the attribute on the action it will giving me to provide `HttpContextAccessor` in constructor can any on help me for the .net core , I have implemented the same code for .net framework  in mvc need help for .net core

```
    public class SessionCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
    {
        private static HttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public SessionCheck(HttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {                
            if (_httpContextAccessor. HttpContext.Session.GetString("Sessionname").ToString() == null )
            {                   
                //FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                filterContext.Result =
               new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
                        {
                              { "action", "LogIn" },
                            { "controller", "Login" }
                         });    
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access HttpContext from `ActionExecutingContext`.
Just change `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` to `filterContext.HttpContext`